# парсинг строки и перевод в вектор, как сделать более грамотно

Tags: c++

```
string str = "12,1,214,3234";
string s;
vector<int> numbers;
int x;
for (size_t i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i)
{
    if (str[i] != ',')
    {
        s += str[i];
    }
    else
    {
        x = atoi(s.c_str());
        s.clear();
        numbers.push_back(x);
    }

}
x = atoi(s.c_str());
s.clear();
numbers.push_back(x);// без дублирования за циклом перевода последнего значения.(более изящно)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно делать проверку внутри цикла на его завершение:

```
auto p_ch{str.begin()};
for(;;)
{
    auto const done{str.end() == p_ch};
    if(done or (',' == (*p_ch)))
    {
        if(not s.empty())
        {
            auto const x{atoi(s.c_str())};
            numbers.push_back(x);
            s.clear();
        }
        if(done)
        {
            break; // for
        }
    }
    else
    {
        assert(::std::isdigit(*p_ch));
        s.push_back(*p_ch);
    }
    ++p_ch;
}
assert(str.end() == p_ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно по-разному... Например:

```
string str = "12,1,214,3234";
vector<int> v;


// Разбор строки на int'ы
istringstream in(str);
for(int n; in>>n; v.push_back(n),in.get());


for(auto i: v) cout << i << endl;
```

Comment: Возможно, код стал бы понятнее, если бы вы засунули v.push_back(n) в тело цикла. Или вообще while(in >> n)